# Unix Export Variables from Tokenised String

Tags: shell, unix, ksh, tokenize

Say I have a string:

```
'EffTimeStamp="20110203-210000"#InputCtxNm="Forigen Exchange Today"#RunType="EOD"#Age="90"
```

Using:

```
echo 'EffTimeStamp="20110203-210000"#InputCtxNm="Forigen Exchange Today"#RunType="EOD"#Region=US#Age="90"' \ |  awk -F# -v OFS="\n" '{for (i=1;i<=NF; i++) printf("%s%s", $i, (i==NF ? "\n" : OFS)) }'
```

I convert it to :

```
EffTimeStamp="20110203-210000"
InputCtxNm="Forigen Exchange Today"
RunType="EOD"
Region=US
Age="90"
```

I want export these as Shell Variables.

Note : Number of Variable in string may vary upon users discretion.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

What's your shell?

Assuming bash, try this:

```
source <(awk -v RS="#" '{print "export " $0}' <<< "$string")
```

For ksh, this should work

```
. <(printf "%s\n" "$string" | awk -v RS="#" '{print "export " $0}')
```

Comment: see edits to my questions : How can this be done in Korn Shell for KSH.

Answer (score 0):

In your awk, use

```
printf("export %s%s"
```

and then replace 'echo' with 'eval'.

Comment: it not working... when I echo the variable it display blank values
and what if instead of awk i use sed :
echo '"EffTimeStamp=20110203-210000#InputCtxNm=Forigen Exchange Today#RunType=EOD"' |   sed 's/^"//;s/=/="/g;s/#/"\n/g'

Comment: please edit your question to include this valuable debugging information. You can include a note as comment like 'see edits to my question.'. Good luck.

Comment: see edits to my questions : 
I tried doing this but resulted in blank exports.
`sac$  eval 'EffTimeStamp="20110203-210000"#InputCtxNm="Forigen Exchange Today"#RunType 
> |  awk -F# -v OFS="\n" '{for (i=1;i<=NF; i++) printf("export %s%s", $i, (i==NF ? "\n" : OFS)) }'
sac$ 
sac$  echo $RunType

sac$ 
sac$ echo $EffTimeStamp

sac$`

Comment: Use glenn's solution (assuming bash).

Comment: see edits to my questions : I cannot use Glenn's Solution I am using Korn Shell (KSH).